# Google Sheets: Trigger script IF value

Tags: google-sheets, triggers

Can someone please help me with this script?

```
function HistoryTrigger() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 if (sheet.getName() == "Status") {
   var activeCell = sheet.getRange("G11");
     if (activeCell.getValue() ="OK") {
        recordHistory();

     }
   }
 }

function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historie");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:B2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

I want the trigger to start when `Status!G11="OK"`, then start `recordHistory()`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`if (activeCell.getValue() =="OK") {`

double `==` is proper syntax for if statements.

You may run this functoin with `onEdit`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Status') { HistoryTrigger(); }
}
```

It'll check each time user change something. It will run when G11 is OK on sheet 'Status'.

To combine all together, I suggest passing `e` into `HistoryTrigger`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
      HistoryTrigger(e);
    }


function HistoryTrigger(e) {

 var ss = e.range.getSheet();
 if (ss.getName() === 'Status') {
   var activeCell = ss.getRange("G11");
     if (activeCell.getValue() == "OK") {
        recordHistory();

     }
   }
 }

function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historie");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:B2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

Comment: Aah, thanks :-)

But do I have to add a trigger to run every minute to check if the cell if G11 is OK, or will it run WHEN G11 is OK?

Comment: The HistoryTrigger function can be set directly to an [OnEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).  Note that the response above will apply when any cell is changed to "OK" and not just Status!G11. To limit this to the one specific cell, set the HistoryTrigger finction as the onEdit trigger per the linked page. Next, change the first line to `function HistoryTrigger(e) {`   Then you can test `if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Status' && e.range.getA1Notation() === "G11"  && e.value == 'OK' ) {` which should test for all 3 requirements (untested)

Comment: Max: I get an error here:
var ss = e.range.getSheet();
Its something like "Cannot read range from undefined"....

Comment: The function can't be run from script editor, it runs automatically when sheet is changed.

Comment: I cant get this working. When I write OK in Status!G11, the trigger do not fire.
But if I run "recordHistory" manually, its working....

Comment: There were 2 mistakes in the code: 1. `==` in if statement. 2. undefined `sheet`, corrected to `ss`. Now code works as trigger.

Comment: Thanks again :-)
I still cant get this working. It works OK when a type OK in Status!G11, but this value in Status!G11 come from a IF-formula.
I think thats because the trigger doesnt fire. Am I correct?

Comment: onEdit trigger fires when user change the data, but it does not work when formula change. You will need a time driven trigger to check the value, changed by formula.